# What's the difference between the 2 ways of definitions of function handle? which is robust and better?

Tags: matlab, conjugate-gradient

Recently, I have been studying **Krylov subspace iterative methods**. I find the matlab robust command **pcg** and the new concept of the function handle to return a **matrix-vector** product. Then I use **help pcg** in matlab command window and find an example as follows:

```matlab
%   compare the difference between two ways of definitions of function handle
clc;clear;
tol = 1e-6;
maxit = 15;
M = diag([10:-1:1 1 1:10]);
%%  way 1 from matlab "help pcg"
n1 = 21;
afun = @(x,n)gallery('moler',n)*x;%  returns A*x
b1 = afun(ones(n1,1),n1);
[x1,flag1,rr1,iter1,rv1] = pcg(@(x)afun(x,n1),b1,tol,maxit,M);



%%  way 2   from myself
n2 = 21;
afun = @(x)gallery('moler',n2)*x;%  returns A*x
b2 = afun(ones(n2,1));
[x2,flag2,rr2,iter2,rv2] = pcg(afun,b2,tol,maxit,M);
[iter1 iter2 flag1 flag2]
[rr1 rr2]
```

As you can see, the 1st way above is from matlab and I find another way to define the function handle of **afun**. And the numerical results is the same with matlab example. It seems that there is no difference  but as we know *MATLAB** always does the best way to give us the code. So I ask whether there is any difference? Which way of function handle definition is better? Any hints and suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MATLAB's definition is

```
afun = @(x,n)gallery('moler',n)*x;%  returns A*x
```

So you can pass as an argument the size `n` of the matrix. If you would run the code for different values of n, you simply need to declare the n and run the code, like:

```
for n1 = 10:21
    % do something
    b1 = afun(ones(n1,1),n1);
    [x1,flag1,rr1,iter1,rv1] = pcg(@(x)afun(x,n1),b1,tol,maxit,M);
    % do something
end
```

Your definition

```
afun = @(x)gallery('moler',n2)*x;
```

clearly specifies to use `n2=21`, so it will create a matrix 21x21, and only and exactly a matrix 21x21. If you need to run it for different values of `n`, you will have to define the function for every different `n`.

```
for n2 = 10:21
    % do something
    afun = @(x)gallery('moler',n2)*x;%  returns A*x
    b2 = afun(ones(n2,1));
    [x2,flag2,rr2,iter2,rv2] = pcg(afun,b2,tol,maxit,M);
    % do something
end
```

In the simple example above, the code will declare and create the `afun` variable on every loop on the for, while in MATLAB's example, the `afun` function is declared only once.

---

Edit: added execution time.

MATLAB has a good discussion on how to [measure the performance of your code](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/measure-performance-of-your-program.html), but essentially you can use the [timeit](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) or the [tic toc](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/tic.html) functions.
To measure part of the code, you can use the `tic`/`toc`, but the recommendation to measure execution time of functions is to use `timeit`. The doc reads:

> Unlike tic and toc, the timeit function calls your code multiple
>   times, and, therefore, considers first-time costs.

Let's then rewrite our code to check execution time. First, define the functions:

```
function [] = matlabfun(num)
    %%  matlab's definition
    tol = 1e-6;  maxit = 1500;
    afun = @(x,n)gallery('moler',n)*x;
    for n1 = 10:num
        % do something
        b1 = afun(ones(n1,1),n1);
        [x1,flag1,rr1,iter1,rv1] = pcg(@(x)afun(x,n1),b1,tol,maxit);
        % do something
    end
end

function [] = myfun(num)
    %%  my definition
    tol = 1e-6;  maxit = 1500;
    for n2 = 10:num
        % do something
        afun = @(x)gallery('moler',n2)*x;%  returns A*x
        b2 = afun(ones(n2,1));
        [x2,flag2,rr2,iter2,rv2] = pcg(afun,b2,tol,maxit);
        % do something
    end
end
```

Then write your main script to measure the execution time of each function:

```
clc;clear;
num = 4e+2;%number of tests

matlab_fun = @() matlabfun(num);
my_fun = @() myfun(num);

timeit(matlab_fun)
timeit(my_fun)
```

The results are:

```
ans =

   19.9332


ans =

   19.6177
```

So, it looks like your definition runs faster than MATLAB's definition. In my computer, though, the difference is not that big.

However, and this I cannot explain for sure why it happens, if you change the order of the statements, you will get a different response:

```
clc;clear;
num = 4e+2;%number of tests

matlab_fun = @() matlabfun(num);
my_fun = @() myfun(num);

timeit(my_fun)
timeit(matlab_fun)
```

The results are:

```
ans =

   19.5554


ans =

   19.4029
```

Now it looks like MATLAB's definition is faster. The reason for that, and this is just my personal thoughts, is that the first call to the `gallery`/`pcg` functions takes longer than the subsequent calls. As if MATLAB has to figure out the path/library/toolbox for these functions and, since it is a first call, it runs some pieces of code to prepare your computer to run it.

This is something I have noticed along the years programming in MATLAB, the first call to a function always takes longer than the rest. So, whichever definition you put first in your code to run is the one that will take longer. I still haven't found a good explanation to why that happens, but it is how MATLAB seems to work. But, hey, just don't worry to much about that.

Comment: I totally get it. This proves the words that I said "MATLAB always does the best way", O(∩_∩)O. Thanks Professor Thales very much.

Comment: But when I implement this in my matlab using a **for loop**, I get the contrary results listed below. Is this results right? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Professor Thales's answer. You mean that in the for loop, matlab just declare the function handle **afun** once, and in my way matlab have to declare the variable **afun** every loop. I thought Matlab will be faster than my way, but I find the contrary results.

I have done a simple test to testify the CPU time for these two different way of definitions of function handle as follows:

```matlab
clc;clear;
num = 4e+2;%number of tests
%%  matlab's definition
tic
tol = 1e-6;  maxit = 1500;
afun = @(x,n)gallery('moler',n)*x;
for n1 = 10:num
    % do something
    b1 = afun(ones(n1,1),n1);
    [x1,flag1,rr1,iter1,rv1] = pcg(@(x)afun(x,n1),b1,tol,maxit);
    % do something
end
toc


%%  my definition
tic
tol = 1e-6;  maxit = 1500;
for n2 = 10:num
    % do something
    afun = @(x)gallery('moler',n2)*x;%  returns A*x
    b2 = afun(ones(n2,1));
    [x2,flag2,rr2,iter2,rv2] = pcg(afun,b2,tol,maxit);
    % do something
end
toc
```

And the results are as follows (my cpu is 8GB memory, and on matlab2018b), the matlab's way is indeed slower than my way. Is this  suitable for the threory? Thanks.

```matlab
Elapsed time is 70.078114 seconds.
Elapsed time is 56.685017 seconds.
```

Comment: I have edited my answer adressing this issue. Check it out :)

Comment: Get it. Very thanks for your detailed and clear explanation. I have learned much from your point view. Thanks Teacher Thales again. Best wishes.